# Wanted to set a Mp3 sound from Raw Resource and change the Default sound of Notification of a mobile not of a Custom Notification

Tags: android, notifications

Wanted to set a Mp3 sound from Raw Resource and change the Default sound of Notification of a mobile not of a Custom Notification i search a lot but all Answers related to custom Notification not Default mobile Notifications and also same want to change Alarm Clock of Mobile App sound i use Ringtone manager but not able to change the default sound of Mobile App Notification and also Alarm Clock sound if anyone help me then i am very thankful to him.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and i want to share this if someone want to add custom sound from raw resource on Notification or Alarm Clock then the answer is.

Uri newUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://com.beautiful.sounds/raw/"+item.getmAudioResourceId());
                                                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                                                        context,
                                                        RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
                                                        newUri
                                                );

and for Alarm Clock just change the RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM